# Is there a way to call an event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a project, I am trying to make a button work based on the events happening in an event listener, so whenever the button has clicked the events in that event listener is supposed to execute, so is there a way to add `<button onclick="EVENT LISTENER"></button>??`

**EDIT:THIS IS THE CODE IM TRYING TO IMPLEMENT IN, I AM TRYING TO FLIP TO THE NEXT PAGE WHEN I CLICK THE BUTTON**

```js
async function nxtbtnclicked() {
    const current2 = versesList.innerHTML
    const numbers2 = current2.match(/\d/g); //to get the numbers from the string
    const nid2 = numbers2[1];
    const finalid = parseFloat(nid2);
    if (finalid < 114) getVersesforpage(finalid + 1)
    if (finalid === 114) getVersesforpage(finalid) //113 > 2 !fix
}

async function getVersesforpage(number) { //to get verses for a certain pagetry
    try {
        const url = `https://api.alquran.cloud/v1/page/${number}/quran-uthmani`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        const ayahs = data.data.ayahs;
        const verses = ayahs.map(ayah => ayah.text);
        return verses;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error:", e.message)
    }

}
  

    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", async (event) => {


        event.preventDefault();
        const {
            number
        } = event.target.elements;
        const value = number.value;

        const json = {
            id: value
        }

        repo.addpagenumber(json) //add the page number to the indexeddb
        const versesdb = await repo.getpageversesById(value)
        if (versesdb === undefined) {
            const verses = await getVersesforpage(value)
            console.log(verses)
            //create an object
            const versesobject = {
                id: value,
                verses: verses
            }

            repo.addpagesverses(versesobject)


        }
        //use db data info

        const {id, verses} = versesdb
        const versesHtml = `
        <h3>رقم الصفحة: ${value}  </h3>
        ${verses}
    `
        document.querySelector('#versesList').innerHTML = versesHtml;


    });
```

```html
  <button id="next-btn" onclick="nxtbtnclicked()"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-3x"></i> </button>
```

Comment: yes, that's how onclick works

Comment: You can also specify it's id and then add listener to this button , actually it's more convenient , if you want code please reply !!

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what `onclick` was designed for. Have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp).

Here an example. When you click the button an alert will pop up saying *"The button was clicked"*.

```js
function handleClick(){
  alert("The button was clicked")
}
```

```html
<button onclick="handleClick()">Click me!</button>
```

You may also attach an event listener in your JavaScript code.

```js
function handleClick(){
  alert("The button was clicked")
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  // initial HTML document has completely loaded now
  
  // get the button using the ID it has been assigned in the HTML
  const myButton = document.getElementById("my-button")
  // attach the event listener here
  // handle the "click" event and whenever that event occurs call the function handleClick()
  myButton.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
});
```

```html
<button id="my-button">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: how can i do it if i don't have a handling function??

Comment: In order to handle button clicks you will have to define one and as far as I can see `nxtbtnclick()` seems to be a handler for your button. Only problem is I can't run your code as you are missing some of the HTML e.g the element with ID "form" is not there. But if I remove all of that and just use your `nxtbtnclicked` method it does work. Essentially you need to write the code you need to flip the page into `nxtbtnclicke()` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could dispatch events:

```js
function rgb(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${+(Math.random()*255)},${+(Math.random()*255)},${+(Math.random()*255)})`;

  console.log("clicked", e.target);
}


function trigger(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log("dispatch click event to container element");
  content.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("click"));
}
```

```css
.content
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 315px;
  height: 200px;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
}
.content > span
{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="content" onclick="rgb(event)">
  <span><button>button 1</button></span>
  <span><button onclick="rgb(event)">rgb()</button></span>
  <span><button onclick="trigger(event)">trigger()</button></span>
  click anywhere
</div>
```